# How to call a jquery method from PHP page loaded through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page where I am loading a series of buttons into a div using jquery/ajax.   This is a script for loading every time the user user scrolls the page.  Each of the buttons are clickable and run a jquery function after being clicked. The problem is when I switched to loading the buttons from a different page the now don't call any method.  If I switch the buttons to calling a pure javascript function it works just fine but I need the button to call a jquery function as the rest of the script, which is quite long, has been done in jquery.

Here is what I am talking about: 
Page A:

```
             $(document).ready(function() {
                 var track_load = 0; //total loaded record group(s)
                 var loading  = false; //to prevents multipal ajax loads
                 var total_groups = '<?php echo $total_groups; ?>';

              $('#results').load("testshareload.php", {'group_no':track_load}, function(result) {
                                 track_load++;
                                 }); //load first group


              $(window).scroll(function() { //detect page scroll
              });

              $('#testerino').on('click', function () {
                    console.log("CALLED");
              });
```

PAGE B: (testshareload.php)

```
<?php
    echo "<input type='button' value='Button' id='testerino'>";
?>
```

It also will not work for me to do this due to the existing code:

```
function testerino() {
      $(document).ready(function() {
      });
}
```

What else can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: script load all  buttons with same id?

Comment: yea they all have the same id, but the attributes are all different and set through php from a mysql database.

Comment: use this code  . instead of assign same id it is batter to assign same class name to all buttons.
$(document).on('click','#testerino', function () {
    console.log("CALLED");
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a click handler for an element that doesn't exist, and this will fail in jQuery. What you need to do is create a DELEGATED handler for the item:

```
$(document).on('click','#testerino', function () {
    console.log("CALLED");
});
```

The document accepts the handler being registered, and later when it gets a click event from an element matching the selector `#testerino` it will fire off the handler.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're binding an event to an element that doesn't exist yet.

As per [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
> must exist at the time your code makes the call to .on()

You have two options:

1. Create the bind in your .load function instead.

Or as per the docs again:

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
> descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
> picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
> delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
> avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

2. Use `$(document).on('click', '#testerino', function() { ...`